# TypeError: hog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'block_norm'

Tags: python

```
import os
from skimage import feature as ft 
import cv2    
def hog_feature(img_array, resize=(64,64)):
    """extract hog feature from an image.
    Args:
        img_array: an image array.
        resize: size of the image for extracture.
    Return:
    features:  a ndarray vector.
    """
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, resize)
    bins = 9
    cell_size = (8, 8)
    cpb = (2, 2)
    norm = "L2"
    features = ft.hog(img, orientations=bins, pixels_per_cell=cell_size,
                        cells_per_block=cpb,block_norm=norm, transform_sqrt=True)
    return features
```

Hog function has this parameter, why is it wrong?

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Confirm that you're using a version >= 0.13. `feature.hog` did not take a `block_norm` argument prior to that as far as I can tell - http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=feature#skimage.feature.hog

Comment: My version is already 0.14，I'll look for it again。